# Different material on different polygon of an editable poly

Tags: 3dsmax

I have a 3d Model in 3ds max and want to use different materials on different side. I convert it into Editable Poly, so the model can be handled on Polygon level. I apply UVW Map modifier to the object for controlling the UVW Tile, but the tile might be different for different faces. How can I control it individually for different face?

Answer (score 0):

Select the face that you want to edit, keep the selection on, and apply the UVW map modifier directly on the selection. This way the UVW map is applied to the selected face only.

Cheers !